# 2 cases for P = NP

Tags: complexity-theory

As we all know the million dollar question in Computer Science P=NP or not. I was trying to understand it and got some doubts please tell me whether I'm right or wrong

N=NP in two cases

> Case 1: We have found an algorithm which can solve a NP-Complete problem in P-Time. This implies that P=NP=NP-Complete. But still we can not say anything about the NP-HARD Problems.
>
> [image: http://s30.postimg.org/k721ni0j5/image.png]
>
> Case 2: We have found an algorithm which can solve a NP-Hard problem in P-Time. This implies that P=NP=NP-Complete=NP-Hard.
>
> [image: http://s15.postimg.org/3po7i4kcr/image.png]

Am I right or I'm missing some point.

Comment: You can include the images in the post, rather than just as links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case 1 is almost correct: if you could solve a single **NP**-complete problem in polynomial time, then every other **NP** problem can be solved by first reducing to the solved problem and then using the polytime algorithm for that. However, even if **P** **NP**, the trivial languages $\emptyset$ and $\Sigma^*$ are not **NP**-complete under many-one reductions, so **NP** $\neq$ **NP**-complete.

Case 2 is incorrect. **NP**-hard is not a complexity class, as such, and **NP**-hard problems can have arbitrarily high complexity. To take an extreme case, the halting problem in **NP**-hard but you wouldn't be able to solve that by proving **P** = **NP**. Also, any **EXP**-complete problem is **NP**-hard, since **NP** $\subseteq$ **EXP**, so any problem in **NP** is reducible to any **EXP**-complete problem. However, by the time hierarchy theorem, **P** $\neq$ **EXP** so there cannot, in fact, be any polytime solution to this **NP**-hard problem, even if **P** = **NP**.

Answer (score 2):

No, your case 2 is wrong.

NP-hard is *definitely* not equal to P. NP-hard includes problems that are not even decidable/computable.

The following diagram might help: it shows that there is no upper bound on how hard NP-hard problems can be.

[image: NP-hard problems are not bounded above]

If we solve some problem in polynomial time, then all problems below that in the diagram will be solvable in polynomial time but there are still NP-hard problems above it which are not.

Comment: Is this Definition is right
"A problem ‘h’ is NP-hard if and only if there is an NP-complete problem ‘c’ that is P-Time reducible to ‘h’ (Cook Reduction). But since any NP-complete problem can be reduced to any other NP-complete problem in polynomial time, all NP-complete problems can be reduced to any NP-hard problem in P-Time. Then if there is a solution to one NP-hard problem in P-Time, there is a solution to all NP-Complete problems in P-Time."

Comment: That is correct (though it's not a definition). A solution in polynomial time to one NP-hard problem gives a polynomial time algorithm for all NP-complete problems (actually all NP problems), but not to all NP-hard problems.

Comment: Can u explain Diagrammatically the meaning of "Then if there is a solution to one NP-hard problem in P-Time, there is a solution to all NP-Complete problems in P-Time."

Comment: Is this the correct diagrammatic representation for Case 2
http://s29.postimg.org/d1u517orr/qwq.png

Comment: you mean for both the 2 above cases the single diagram that you have showed is correct.

Comment: @Max **NP**-hard probably doesn't include **NP**. For example, languages in **L** are in **NP** but are very unlikely to be **NP**-hard.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: you're right -- as my diagram shows.

Comment: @Max So you should probably delete the comment that claims the opposite...

Comment: Or as I facetiously like to call undecidable but recursively enumerable problems, $O(\infty)$ or $O(\omega)$.  =P